# How to added the SQL query used generate the excel file in DATAGRIP IDE?

Tags: oracle, ide, oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

I'm a SQL developer user, usually, I extract data from Oracle database and store them into excel files on a daily basis, the nice thing about Oracle's SQL Developer when exporting the file into excel file, you get two worksheets one for your data, and another worksheet contain the SQL query that used to generate this report.


Now I'm using DATAGRIP IDE from JetBrains, I noticed when I export the file into excel sheet I only get the data and I don't the SQL query that I used to generate this excel file.
is there any way to add the SQL query to the exported file?

[image]

Comment: You could just keep using SQLDev :) But seriously,  you having any issues there we can improve for you?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I'm a big fan of SQL developer, but I'm dealing with Oracle and MySQL at the same time so with DataGrip that is possible ...besides DataGrip has many beautiful themes on the same hand SQL developer has only 4 themes.

Comment: For myself, you're not wrong.  On themes,  check github, lots of nice ones

Comment: @thatjeffsmith how to get them through Github? I don't see any option in SQL developers that allow you to import thems?

Comment: Manual process, example https://draculatheme.com/oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thanks I will consider checking them, I hope Oracle in the next SQL developer versions will consider added more themes and more beautiful things related to the appearance other than that SQL developer is the best, only need more themes ...thems that can change the whole UI not only the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to include the SQL tab automatically. But every grid has it's own "View Query" option where you can see and copy the needed SQL.

[image]

To have this tab, please create a feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: I marked this answer as correct because this the least I could do,I hope jetbrains consider adding this feature to datagrip soon .